# Jordan chain when matrix has only one eigenvalue.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

> A $12\times 12$ matrix has sole eigenvalue $3$. It is given that the kernels
>   of $A-3I$, $(A-3I)^{2}$, $(A-3I)^{3}$
>   and $(A-3I)^{4}$ have dimensions $4$, $7$, $9$ and $10$ respectively. What
>   are the possible jordan forms of $A$?

I would have thought to approach this problem by constructing a chain
diagram like this

using up $4$ vertical crosses to make $4$ in first column then the difference
to $7$ of in the next column then

the difference of two to make up $9$ in the next then difference of
one to give $10$, which would have resulted

in a diagram like this

xxxx

xxx

xx

x

And a corresponding jordan form of $j_{4}(3)\bigoplus j_{3}(3) \bigoplus j_{2}(3)\bigoplus j_{1}(3)$
reading down the chain diagram, however the answer is

apparently $j_{1}(3)\bigoplus j _{2} (3) \bigoplus j _{3}(3)\bigoplus j_{6}(3)$.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not done yet because you haven't reached 12. You're only at 10. However, there's only one chain in your diagram that hasn't terminated. So that one has to be where you put the remaining 2. So you get 6,3,2,1.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** What does "Kernel of $A-3I$ has dimension 4" tell you?

> There are exactly 4 jordan blocks with.

**Hint:** Furthermore, What does "Kernel of $(A-3I)^2$ has dimension 7" tell you?

> There are exactly $7-4=3$ jordan blocks with dimension at least 2.

Continue on, and you will reach the conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the last two to reach $12$, kernels of $(A-3I)^5$ and $(A-3I)^6$ should have dimensions $11$ and $12$.